# Best way to migrate one to many to many to many juction table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a many to many table with one staff to many clients. Based on a new requirement I have to now add many clients to many staff.

My table has over 1000 rows, and my question is how do I write a T-SQL statement that will migrate the data correctly from the client table and insert into my junction table called `StaffClient`?

Here is my current `Client` table where `ClientID` is the primary key and `StaffID` is the foreign key. One staff member has many clients

```
ClientId                                StaffId
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
F7DD6029-27AF-A9ED-57A2-FE25B815BFA7    3AA1C003-F0F1-49AB-84A3-26E747EE4581
1CB8FE0F-2D21-4E5B-99E9-FBBDF0EEBDC7    3AA1C003-F0F1-49AB-84A3-26E747EE4581
D87659C2-7916-4048-A165-F4BB0B4937D3    NULL
E18E3C8D-92DB-4627-BB73-F43CB67A3AEE    NULL
50795DB2-085E-46FD-97DE-F33B6AE39EE0    NULL
45FE2A69-583F-CBF7-750A-E9C93FC52D27    NULL
86B13CB5-41DB-4016-8D3D-E467B0CD6EE9    NULL
24508726-61CE-4C27-B6D7-DBABBAAD141B    8E3990F4-68B7-4F0F-AD40-923ECAC7A476
66FDFC91-1E27-4AEE-A8F6-D79B54CF601D    NULL
A99A0D77-612F-47B7-A82B-D0E51ADF1E49    NULL
59388388-5AEC-4AC5-BD54-CF802734AAD1    B7B0897A-8D40-408E-841B-598C3C425762
79747776-5867-458F-8FD5-CDD299AA3595    NULL
F5A8EFF1-3996-424C-9EF8-CD60D0B900DE    3AA1C003-F0F1-49AB-84A3-26E747EE4581
```

My question is how do I write a SQL statement for over 1000 rows that will now go to my junction table called `StaffClient`.

Here is the SQL for my junction table

```
CREATE TABLE StaffClient 
(
    StaffId uniqueidentifier,
    ClientId uniqueidentifier
    PRIMARY KEY (StaffId, ClientId),
    FOREIGN KEY (StaffId) REFERENCES Staff(StaffId),
    FOREIGN KEY (ClientId) REFERENCES Client(ClientId)
);
```

Comment: I don't understand your current status and where exactly you're tripped up.

Comment: Is this not just a straight `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE StaffId IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this select statement to ensure that the correct data is returned:

```
SELECT ClientId, StaffId 
FROM Client 
WHERE StaffId IS NOT NULL;
```

Once you've verified, run this:

```
INSERT INTO StaffClient (ClientId, StaffId) 
    SELECT ClientId, StaffId 
    FROM Client 
    WHERE StaffId IS NOT NULL;
```